# How to easily copy a folder from Files app in iphone to a PC?

Tags: iphone, ios

I tried to use File Sharing stuff via itunes but it seems their Files app doesn't support File Sharing? (am I missing something or this is really dumb?)

Any way to easily or with a free app to achieve this, specifically from files inside Files app?

Comment: If both the iPhone and the PC are in the same network, you could share a volume/disk on the PC, access this within Files and then copy files.

Comment: Thanks, that actually works but it's still a bit cumbersome. So it's normal FileSharing from itunes doesn't work from Files app, right?

Comment: What version of iTunes and what OS is in play @AlfaTeK ?

Answer (score 2):

If both the iPhone and the PC are in the same network, you could share a volume/disk on the PC, access this within Files and then copy files.

You can also connect to [iCloud on Windows](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102595) and exchange files that way (or even store them in iCloud directly).

Answer (score -1):

Use iCloud.com in your browser

Comment: Can you explain the steps required to use icloud.com to access files available in Files.app?

Comment: Sure. Log in with your Apple ID and password. Click on the graphic for iCloud Drive. On the left side of the screen click on the Browse button. You'll see Data Libraries from various applications as well as folders you've created to hold files. You can download whatever you want to the hard drive of the PC you are on.

Comment: Can you edit this into the answer? And, as far as I can see, this does not give access to files only stored on the iPhone.